# sklearn.impute SimpleImputer: why does transform() need fit_transform() first?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

sklearn provides `transform()` method to Apply one-hot encoder.

to use `transform()` method, `fit_transform()` is needed before calling `transform()` method, otherwise

```
np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2], [np.nan, 2]])
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
my_imputer.transform(df)
```

error shows up

> NotFittedError: This SimpleImputer instance is not fitted yet. Call
>   'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

calling `fit_transform()` before `transform()`

```
my_imputer.fit_transform(df)
my_imputer.transform(df)
```

fix this error.

the question is, why does `transform()` need `fit_transform()`?

Comment: If you call the `fit_transform` only, there's no need to call `transform` at all. `fit_transform` first fits the data and then transforms it. Or you can call first `my_imputer.fit(df)` and the `my_imputer.transform(df)`. Both are the same.

Comment: Basically, you need to fit the data first before transforming it

Comment: actually the transform_fit hold the two steps which are fitting and transforming or you can say filling the missing values . for your question why we need transform first because it' s kind of training the impute about the data and deduce the mean or median … to fill out the missing values

Answer (score 14):

During `fit()` the imputer learns about the mean, median etc of the data, which is then applied to the missing values during `transform()`.

`fit_transform()` is just a shorthand for combining the two methods. So essentially:

- `fit(X, y)` :-  Learns about the required aspects of the supplied data and returns the new object with the learned parameters. It does not change the supplied data in any way.
- `transform()` :- Actually transform the supplied data to the new form.

`fit_transform(df)` is not required to be called before transform. Only `fit()` is needed to be called. Generally the sequence you described is done with train and test split of data. Something like:

```
# Combining the learning of parameters from training data and transforming into a single step.
X_train_new = my_imputer.fit_transform(X_train)

# We dont want to learn about test data, only change it according to previously learnt information
X_test_new = my_imputer.transform(X_test)
```

The above code snippet can be broken into:

```
# It learns about the data and does nothing else
my_imputer.fit(X_train)

# Calling transform to apply the learnt information on supplied data
X_train_new = my_imputer.transform(X_train)
X_test_new = my_imputer.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: do you not need to fit a new imputer on the test data to avoid data leakage?

Comment: @Maths12 No. Leakage happens when you fit (learn from) on the whole data and test data is made out from that. Never fit on test data.

Comment: just to be crystal clear , so when i impute nans or infs on my data with mode, whatever mode vaue i get from train i populate my test and validation with this?

Comment: once i apply this how do i convert it back to dataframe retaining the index?

Comment: @Maths12 I'm sorry but I dont follow your question. Do you want to combine the train and test again into a single dataframe? Or different dataframes? Which index are you talking about? Can you make an example or post a new question with what you want.